# Get Classic ASP session variable into inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic, session-variables

How do I get a session variable into this JavaScript on a Classic ASP page?

```vb
report = Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">window.open(""http://somesite.com/payvoucher.aspx?usercode=session(USERCODE)"",""_self"");</script>")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate the session variable `Session("USERCODE")` into the string using the string concatenation character `&`, unlike other languages VBScript doesn't infer a variable just by placing it inside the string.

```vb
Dim report: report = "<script type=""text/javascript"">window.open(""http://somesite.com/payvoucher.aspx?usercode=" & Session("USERCODE") & """,""_self"");</script>"
Call Response.Write(report)
```